# Same route in multiple role and route group?

Tags: laravel

I have route which I want to authorize on more than 1 one role.I have created 2 route group one is admin and other one is employee and there is a route abc.com/abc which I want to accessible on both roles. Admin routes are:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','role:admin|hr-manager|manager ']],function(){
    Route::get('employee',['as'=>'employee','uses'=>'EmployeeController@employeeList']); 
    Route::get('leave-type',['as'=>'leave.type','uses'=>'LeaveController@getLeaveType']);
}
```

Employee routes are:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:employee']], function(){
    Route::get('leave-type',['as'=>'leave.type','uses'=>'LeaveController@getLeaveType']);
}
```

Now when i login with admin i can't access leave-type route because admin user doesn't have employee role but when i assign admin user to employee role it will be accessible, and admin user can not be an employee so how can i accessible this route on both role.

Using laravel 5.4 and zizaco/entrust for ACL system. so please let me how what type of problem is this and how can get the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laravel only supports one route definition per method/url.

Comment: It looks like employee is a subtype of the others so an admin, hr-manager or manager "user" is always an employee. If so I'd suggest you to check the 'role' middleware to make sure that the more specific roles have access to the "employees" routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more routes that are available to a base group and then a specific subset for others I'd suggest to reorganize the routes file to something as follows:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    //Routes available to all users
    Route::get('leave-type',['as'=>'leave.type', 'uses'=>'LeaveController@getLeaveType']);

    //Routes available to employees
    Route::middleware(['role:employee'])->group(function () {

    });

    //Routes available to Admin, HR Manager and Manager
    Route::middleware(['role:admin|hr-manager|manager'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('employee', ['as'=>'employee', 'uses'=>'EmployeeController@employeeList']); 
    });
});
```

Comment: not working . i want to use leave-type when both user log in.

Comment: what is not working? under the previous code there is only one route "leave-type" that you could use if the user is auth and has employee role. If the issue is about the "role" middleware I'd suggest to check it in the ``` zizaco/entrust``` package page.

Comment: i have created a global route group with auth middleware and under global group , define further route group with employee role middleware , admin role middleware like this
route::group([middleware => 'auth'], function(){

leave-type (which accessible for both roles)

route::group([middleware => 'role:employee'], function(){
// other employee route

}
route::group([middleware => 'role:admin|manager|etc'], function(){
// other route will access with admin/manger role

}
});


so please confirm is it right practice or not.
thanks for you help btw.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if it match your goals.

Comment: `route::group([middleware => 'auth'], function(){ 


leave-type (which accessible for both roles)
 route::group([middleware => 'role:employee'], function(){ 
// other employee route 

} 

route::group([middleware => 'role:admin|manager|etc'], function(){

 // other route will access with admin/manger role 

} 

});`

Comment: kindly check my last comment , please assure that is it seems like your last updated answer?

Comment: kindly check the last comment.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer accordingly? Thank you :)